# Extend class in class property?

Tags: php

Suppose that I've this class:

```
class Loader 
{
     function library($name)
     {
          require $name . '.php';
     }
}
```

and now I include the class `foo` ($name) inside my controller, like this:

```
class Controller
{
    function __construct()
    {
         $this->load = new Loader();
    }
}

class Child_Controller extends Controller
{
    function __construct()
    {
         parent::__construct();
         $this->load->library('foo'); 
         init();
    }
}
```

is possible, for example, access to the included class inside `$this`? Like:

```
class Child_Controller extends Controller
{
    //..construct above..

    function init()
    {
        $this->print('some text');
    }
}
```

where `print` is a method of `foo`, the class included:

```
class Foo
{
    function print($message)
    {
         echo "your message: " . $message;
    }
}
```

So, summing, I want include in the child controller, in `$this`, all the method of the included class by the Loader class extended by the base controller. Is this possible?

Or another idea would be create dynamically in the Child_Controller, a property that take the name of the included class, so, for call the method of `foo` I can do something like:

```
$this->Foo->print('some text');
```

Comment: No, that's not possible. Also you would possibly get conflicts with same named class methods. Make a new property and assign it an instance of the class.

Comment: Yes, you can. But it requires a lot of work. Actually, autoload/composer is what you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't do that however you can do something similar in storing `Foo` in a generic property like this:

```
class Child_Controller 
{
    private $lib;

    function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->lib = $this->load->library('Foo');
        $this->init();
    }

    function init()
    {
        $this->lib->print('Hello World!');
    }
}
```

If you want to instantiate multiple libraries then rather than using a dynamic name for the variable you should use an array with the library name as the key, like this:

```
class Child_Controller 
{
    private $libs = [];

    function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->libs['Foo'] = $this->load->library('Foo');
        $this->init();
    }

    function init()
    {
        $this->libs['Foo']->print('Hello World!');
    }
}
```

If you can't use an array and absolutely *must* use a variable name you can do that like this:

```
class Child_Controller 
{
    function __construct()
    {
        $var = 'Foo';
        $this->{$var} = $this->load->library($var);
        $this->init();
    }

    function init()
    {
        $this->Foo('Hello World!');
    }
}
```

Comment: Uhm I like this example, one question: I try this in my code but unfortunately I get: `Fatal error: Call to a member function print on null`, maybe in the `library` function I need to return the include?

Comment: Yes, the `library` function needs to return the instantiated class.

Comment: Okay, thank you very much. I've only problem right now. If I do this: `var_dump($this->libs['foo']);` I get: `int (1)` and on this call `$this->libs['foo']->print()` I'll get this error: `Call to a member function handleLogin() on integer`. Seems that the return return an integer instead of the class? What happen? Thanks again.